# Initialize instance variables outside of Python class

Tags: python, class, initialization, instance-variables

#### Edit

In comments inheritance was suggested however this is already being done and I've added additional code snippet to show.

---

There are a few similar questions of initializing instance variables outside of `__init__` where instance variables are initialized further down in the class within another `def` function (method). This question isn't a duplicate of those questions.

I have three classes all declaring the same `self.xxxx` instance variables after the `def __init__`:

```py
class AskQuestion(simpledialog.Dialog):
    """ Prepends "\n" to text passed.
        Appends "\n\nAre you sure?\n" to text passed.
        Allows text to be highlighted and copied to clipboard with CTRL+C.
        Blocks other windows from getting focus
        MON_FONTSIZE is temporary font size until configuration file set up.
    """

    def __init__(self, parent, title=None, text=None, confirm='yes',
                 align='center', thread=None, icon='warning'):
        self.confirm = confirm      # Append "Are you sure?" line?
        self.align = align          # data (text lines) alignment
        self.thread = thread        # The thread run before button click
        self.loop_no = 1            # Loop counter (not used yet)
        self.data = text            # data (text lines) for text box
        self.text = None            # Textbox widget
        self.icon = icon            # Warning, Error, Info, Question icons
        try:
            self.font = (None, MON_FONTSIZE)
        except NameError:
            self.font = (None, 10)

        # Shared functions
        self.wait_window = wait_window_func
        #self.body = body(self, parent)
        #self.body = body

        simpledialog.Dialog.__init__(self, parent, title=title)
```

How can these lines of code be spun out into a global function which is called to initialize the variables? I'm searching for a technique similar to the bash `.` (source command) or the C `#include` command except variables won't be sourced from another file, simply a global function within the current file (module).

FYI I'm looking for consistency and code reduction for tkinter simpledialog class wrappers for ShowInfo, AskQuestion, AskString, etc.

Comment: Create a base class that your three classes inherit from?

Comment: If all three classes have same init , insted creadte one class and then inherit it

Comment: refer this [link](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_inheritance.asp)

Comment: @NikhilSingh Thanks for the link. However inheritance is already being used and I updated question to show code.

Comment: @IainShelvington It already inherits a base class from tk simpledialog. I added a few lines of code above and below original code snippet to reveal.

Comment: so why not use multiple inheritance

Comment: @NikhilSingh because I inherited COBOL, BASIC, Assembly language, RPG and C. When I try to do something in OOPS I end up with an Oops!!! If you could take the code above and post an answer using it I'd appreciate it.

Comment: this is not a problem, you can use multiple inheritance like this `class AskQuestion(simpledialog.Dialog,myparentclass):`

Comment: @NikhilSingh *light goes on*

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: @NikhilSingh It means I was ***in the dark*** and thiinking something like `class` -> `class` -> `class`. But you said `class` = `class` + `class` and that made the ***light turn on***. I'll come back and post an answer soon with end results.

Comment: @NikhilSingh Please add an answer. I'd be happy to accept and upvote!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in a a case where your classes share init methods you can reduce code by inherting them, like this

```
class A(B):
```

where B is a parent class, also according to the question you can inherit more than one classes,like this

```
class A(B,C):
```

I am providing  a generic answer to avoid the same discussion as in comments

Comment: I should point class C must be before class A.